# MySQL return ID with smallest count

Tags: mysql, count, unique, distinct

I'm trying to get an ID from a table based on which ID has the least entries using only a single query.  Is it possible to do that in just one query?

For example:

```
----------------------
|   ID   | Article_ID|
----------------------
|    1   |      7    |
----------------------
|    1   |      3    |
----------------------
|    1   |      4    |
----------------------
|    2   |      5    |
----------------------
```

I would want it to return "2" for the ID "2" because it only has 1 count versus ID 1 which has 3 count.

I know that I could accomplish this by first running a query to get a list of all of the IDs and then doing a loop to get each IDs count and then finally comparing them but I wanted to know if it was possible to do all of this in a single query instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the first row from the following cursor:

```
select id from (
  select id, count(id) as c 
    from <table name> group by id 
) as x order by c limit 1
```

Comment: add a "limit 1" clause at the end, and you got it

Comment: Thanks, I'm not very familiar with mysql syntax. I mainly work with Oracle.

Comment: Klas, thanks for the help - I tried the following but got an error:
select id from (
  select id, count(id) c 
    from authors_article  group by id 
) order by c limit 1

Error: Every derived table must have its own alias

Comment: I've added an alias for the derived table.

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I needed, TYVM.

Answer (score 0):

My favorite way of getting this data is by using a self join (i might have the < operator backwards, i didn't test it.

```
SELECT t1.ID, t1.Article_ID
FROM table t1
    LEFT JOIN table t2 ON t1.id = t2.id AND t1.article_id < t2.article_id
WHERE t2.id is null
```

This would be returned from the query, in case it's helpful, even though it doesn't exactly answer the question.

```
-------------------
| ID | Article_ID |
-------------------
| 1  | 3          |
-------------------
| 2  | 5          |
-------------------
```

Comment: Not what he is asking for. Will only work if the lowest count is 1

Comment: Your right. I should read it a bit closer. Wasn't thinking it would be that simple of a question.